# django - Can't connect from remote devices to specific server - connection timed out

Tags: python, django, server, firewall

I'm aware this question has been asked before but mine is a problem the answers to those questions cannot solve. Whenever I try to access the site through other devices, it just loads forever and then says "this webpage took too long to respond". I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

I've already tried:

- Running the command as `manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`
- Running the command as `manage.py runserver 192.168.1.10:8000`
- Setting `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to `192.168.1.10`
- Setting an inbound & outbound rule on the firewall in advanced security
- *Restarting the computer (because why not)*
- Downgrading Django to 2.0.0 because I could connect with other devices to a different server running 2.0.0. Didn't work.

And yes, my other devices are definitely on the same network and the local IP address is correct.

I have no idea what else to do. I am able to access the website from my local computer through the local address, but not from other devices. What am I doing wrong?

I'm running Django 2.0.7.

*EDIT:* I am able to connect to a different server, but for some reason not this one. I checked if it was the difference in versions that mattered but it didn't (that server ran 2.0.0, which also produced the same problem in this server).

Comment: What other devices are you using? Are they on the same network? What is the"local address" you are trying?

Comment: @DanielRoseman An android tablet and an android phone. They are on the same network. The local address is my local address as presented when using `ipconfig`, and yes, I'm certain it is the correct address. I can access the website from my local computer even using the local address and not via `localhost`. (See edit)